# what is 0xFF in C#?

Tags: c++

What is 0xFF in C++? What should I write if I want to convert that to C#?

Answer (score 11):

0xFF is a hexadecimal integer which is 255 in decimal:

FF<sub>16</sub> = 255<sub>10</sub>

In [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) you can use it the same way as in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c](/questions/tagged/c), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), [objective-c++](/questions/tagged/objective-c%2b%2b), [java](/questions/tagged/java) and many, many other languages:

```
int x = 0xFF;
if (x == 255) {
  // will always happen
} else {
  throw unicornNukedProcessingUnitException; // will never happen
}
```

---

Hexadecimal numbers are often used to represent octet (byte) values, since you can represent all possible values of an octet with just two hexadecimal digits and surprisingly, the highest value you can represent with two hexadecimal digits is FF, which is 255, which equals the highest value one octet can hold. :)

Comment: @David Heffernan: FF in base 16 equals 255 in base 10.

Comment: I guess there is a subscript that my phone is not respecting hence it looks funny to me. Sorry. I don't see that OP needs to be educated about hex. I just thought the question was what syntax is needed to write a hex literal.

Comment: @David Heffernan yep, it's in subscript :)

Answer (score 1):

You write it exactly the same way in C# as you do in C++.

Answer (score 0):

That's the hexidecimal number `FF`.  Without proper context it's kind of hard to tell you what exactly it's for or what to do to "convert" it to C#.